# Swipe gesture on all screen with textView at the top locked

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe, locked

I need to implement the swipe of the viewpager, whose gesture is extended to the entire screen. But in the top I would like to leave blocked TextView (app title).
I hope I have been clear because I do not have the opportunity for the moment to put links. Thank you

Comment: why not remove the `TextView` in the view pager and place it outside so it won't get affected. **Tip** use the same background color so it will show that it is inside the view pager

Comment: Why don't you use the `Toolbar`?

Comment: I tried to remove it and leave it fixed but swipe on that area does not work.

Comment: At the top of the screen I would like to put the title of the app in large. Under a descriptive part of the app that changes through the swipe, but I would like the user to use the swipe across the screen, leaving the title locked.

Comment: Here's my solution! I entered the data that must remain in basic activity. Framelayout that are part of the viewpager I have inserted them without the background and with the attribute height = match parent.